# Solutions for a multivariate linear equation with constraints

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation of the form:

$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ... + a_nx_n = k, k ∈ Z^+, k ≤ n, a_i ∈ Z^+, x_i ∈ R$

with the constraints:

$0 ≤ x_i ≤ 1, i = 1, 2,...,n$

and

$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = 1$

The coefficients are known. How to generate solutions?

Comment: The solution may not exist. Suppose $n=1$, $a_1=1$, $k=100$. Then the only solution would be $x_1 = 100$ which does not satisfy all constraints.

Comment: @induction601 then how to get solutions for cases in which solutions do exist? btw now I've added k ≤ n

Comment: Could you also provide some conditions on $a_i$'s? Even though $k \le n$, when $n=1$, $a_1 = 1/100$, and $k=1$, the only solution would be $x_1=100$.

Comment: @induction601 $a_i ∈ Z^+$. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

For n=1 we have x1=1, therefore we have a solution only if a1=k. For n=2 we get x1=1-x2 and (a2-a1)x2= k-a1 therefore we get a solution for x1 and  x2 only if (k-a1)/(a2-a1) is between 0 and 1. For n>2 solve x1+x2+...+xn=1 for x1 and substitute in a1.x1+a2.x2+...+an.xn=k. You will get (a2-a1)x2+(a3-a1)x3 + ... +(an-a1)xn=k-a1. Now you more freedom to find solutions depending on the coefficients and the value of k.